# Angular JS authorization - check user role before loading the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing cms front-end in Angular JS and I don't know how to deal with authorize user to see particular content when user first load the app. I have working solution when user is already log in and just navigate from page to page. I do it this way:

```js
angular.module("myApp")
.run ($rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthServ) ->
    $rootScope.$on '$stateChangeStart', (event, next) ->
      if next.data
        authorizedRoles = next.data.authorizedRoles
        unless AuthServ.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)
          event.preventDefault()
          if AuthServ.isAuthenticated()
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized)
          else
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated)
```

When user change the route, the AuthServ.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles) is fired.

When user logs in I get token and user data from server. Token is stored in local storage and user data are stored in memory (in the scope of top level controller). In the user data I have an info about his role, so I can check if he's authorized to see particular content.

Now let's assume that user is logged in and he reload the page. I still have the token as this is in localStorage but I loose user data (so I don't know what is his role). I don't want to show any content to user before I get his data again from server. So my question is how to resolve this ? Where and when should I make the request to server for user data ?

I thought that solution could be to manually bootstrap the app. I tried to do something like this:

```js
app = angular.module('myApp', [])

fetchData = ->
 injector = angular.injector(['ng'])
 $http = injector.get('$http')
 API_URI = injector.get('API_URI')
 $localStorage = injector.get('$localStorage')

 $http.get("#{API_URI}/users/me?token=#{$localStorage.token}")
  .success (data) ->
   app.constant('USER_DATA', data)

bootstrapApplication = ->
 angular.element(document).ready ->
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])

fetchData().then(bootstrapApplication)
```

The problem with this code is that I don't have access to $localStorage service and API_URI constant. I need them to get token and to dynamically change url (development, production).

So what is the best solution ? Maybe storing user role in local storage as well ?

Any help would appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular's resolve in your routes configuration. Here is an example where I am resolving 'user' for a particular route. It must resolve before angular will load this route.

```
app.config( [ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function( $routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/somePath', {
                templateUrl: "someView.html",
                controller: "someController",
                resolve: {
                    user: function( authService ){
                        return authService.getUser();
                    }
                }
            }
        );

    }
]);
```

Here is the service(factory in this case) to go along with it. I am checking to see if auth.user exists first so there won't be a request on each route change:

```
app.factory('authService', [ '$http', '$q',
    function( $http, $q ) {

        var pub = {};

        pub.user = null;

        pub.getUser = function() {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if( pub.user ) {
                deferred.resolve( pub.user );
            }

            else{
                $http.get('/someAuthUrl').then(function( user ) {
                    pub.user = user;
                    deferred.resolve( user );
                });
            }

            return deferred.promise;

        };

        return pub;

    }
]);
```

And then finally the controller which will not load until the auth function has resolved with your needed user data. You can access the user object now through injection.

```
app.controller( 'someController', [ '$scope', 'user',
    function( $scope, user ) {

        //Controller runs here only when user is resolved.
        // Anything resolved will be passed in as your last dependency.
        $scope.user = user;

    }
]);
```

In this case you could have injected the service into the controller instead and use authService.user as we know it's available.

```
app.controller( 'someController', [ '$scope', 'authService',
    function( $scope, authService ) {

        $scope.user = authService.user;

    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. What I don't like in this approach is that I have to user resolve on every single route in my case. This is because user can refresh the page in every place in cms. Resolve is also evil, as if server doesn't respond fast, the user might think that application doesn't respond and nothing happened.

Comment: You make some good points on the negatives of using resolve. I'll give some more thought and see if I can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is because whenever you reload/navigate new instance of controller is created and your user data in controller is lost. Best way to do is to move the logic of authenticating and storing data to a Service and use that service in the controller, this way you won't lose the data on refresh/navigation

Comment: I have no problem with keeping user data when navigating between pages. As you mentioned user data are in fact stored in separate service and in controller I just assign them to scope. It doesn't matter if you keep your data in service -> you still have them only in memory. So on page refresh you lose them. So this is a question: how to manage user data to keep them even if user refresh the page ?

Comment: That was the point if you keep in service it won't get lost on refresh.

Comment: I don't think so. Service is only keep in memory. So when you refresh the page the service have to be recreated again. Any data that are not keep in persistent memory (like local storage will be lost). Other solution could be again ask server about user data.

Comment: can you share you controller and service code as well and btw by refresh i meant navigation to new view not complete page refresh. Complete page refresh would of course recreate everything

Comment: I see :) The question is about complete page refresh, no view change/refresh. I wonder how to again retrieve the user data from server, before I check user role (user role comes from server).

Comment: You can keep the user_info in local storage, or can fetch user info based on token if token exists in local storage

Comment: I thought about fetching data from server as I have special endpoint for it. But as you can see in the code I included I check user role on event $stateChangeStart. So user refresh the page, the app asks server about user data. In the meantime the event $stateChangeStart is fired. This is really probable that callback on $stateChangeStart will check user role, before data are retrieved from server. So to avoid this problem I store token and user role in local storage and only ask server for the rest user data. However, I don't know if this is the best approach.